# Hue parameter in seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am having a problem with Facetgrid: when I use the ***hue*** parameter, the x-labels show up in the wrong order and do not match the data. Loading the Titanic dataset in ipython:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
g = sns.FacetGrid(titanic, col='pclass', hue='survived')
g = g.map(sns.swarmplot, 'sex', 'age')
```

Facetgrid with Hue:
[image: Facetgrid with Hue]

From this it seems that there are more females than males, but this is not true.

If I now remove the ***hue*** option, then I get a correct distribution: there are more males than females across all pclasses.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(titanic, col='pclass')
g = g.map(sns.swarmplot, 'sex', 'age')
```

Facetgrid without Hue:
[image: Facetgrid without Hue]

What's going on here?
I am using Seaborn 0.7.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are going to use `FacetGrid` with one of the categorical plotting functions, you need to supply order information, either by declaring the variables as categorical or with the `order` and `hue_order` parameters:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(titanic, col='pclass', hue='survived')
g = g.map(sns.swarmplot, 'sex', 'age', order=["male", "female"], hue_order=[0, 1])
```

[image]

However, it is generally preferable to use `catplot`, which will take care of this bookkeeping for you and also save you some typing:

```
g = sns.catplot("sex", "age", "survived", col="pclass", data=titanic, kind="swarm")
```

[image]