# How to bring the blue bars in this histogram plot to the front?

Tags: python, histogram

Is there a code that can bring the blue bars in this histogram plot to the front? If I remove alpha I can't see the blue bars at all. I'm using Python3 and Seaborn for this plot

Thank you in advance

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue='credit.policy', palette='coolwarm', height =5, aspect=2)
g = g.map(plt.hist, 'fico', alpha=0.8, bins=30).add_legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hue parameter in seaborn FacetGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863342/hue-parameter-in-seaborn-facetgrid).  Probably by using the `order` and `hue_order` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @trenton-mckinney, you can use `hue_order` to control the order in which your categories are plotted. Compare:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.25, size=(1000,)), 'category':0}),pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.normal(loc=1, size=(1000,)), 'category':1})])



g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue='category', palette='coolwarm', height=5, aspect=2, hue_order=[0,1])
g = g.map(plt.hist, 'data', alpha=0.8, bins=30).add_legend()
```

[image]

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue='category', palette='coolwarm', height=5, aspect=2, hue_order=[1,0])
g = g.map(plt.hist, 'data', alpha=0.8, bins=30).add_legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with following code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(df[df.Private == 'No']['F.Undergrad'], alpha = 0.6,color='c')
plt.hist(df[df.Private == 'Yes']['F.Undergrad'],alpha = 0.9,color='g')
plt.show()
```

Output of above code,

[image]

```
plt.hist(df[df.Private == 'Yes']['F.Undergrad'],alpha = 0.6,color='g')
plt.hist(df[df.Private == 'No']['F.Undergrad'], alpha = 0.9,color='c')
plt.show()
```

Output of above code,

[image]